# Login Form With Entity Framework and 3 layer architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I want to write a login form.

**How much my code is correct? please guide me.**

```
PhonebookDatabaseEntities context = new PhonebookDatabaseEntities();

public bool Accunt(string username ,string password)
{

    bool exists = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password);
    return exists;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not clear yr question. if `context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password);` works correctly then it fine but it would be better u return the user

```
public User Accunt(string username ,string password) 
{
  return context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password); 
}
```

and later on u can check if it's null then credentials are wrong otherwise u check if u.IsActive ... u create appropriate messages for user in BLL and yr UI layer display them to client.

Comment: i get error cannot implicitly convert type data access layer.user to bool.

Comment: use public User Accunt(string username ,string password)